# What is the best way to control RS485 Tx enable on ZYNQ, FPGA

Tags: c, fpga, modbus, rs485, zynq

I am testing infrared temperature sensor. It is connected to SP485(converter rs485 to rs232?) which is connected to ZYNQ,FPGA. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmCPy.png)

I have to input High when I send Tx. After all of messages was sent, I will input Low to this Enable pin.

Simple approach is to do with one bit width GPIO.
Make High just before Write(). After Write() is finished, make GPIO LOW.
I thought..it will be work. but it wasn't.
Code is like as below...(I use libmodbus library to communicate using rs485)

---

`write(fd,"1",1); // make gpio(enable pin) high.
    req_length = modbus_send_raw_request(ctx, raw_req, 6 * sizeof(uint8_t)); //write
    write(fd,"0",1);//After write(), make gpio low to receive messages from sensor.
    int response_length = modbus_receive_confirmation(ctx, rsp);`

---

This code was not working properly. Write() is not write immediately..
or the prosess is working independently.(so there is possibility that when I input Low, write() is not finished).

I don't know reason actually. it's just my assuming.

So I added usleep();

---

`write(fd,"1",1); // make gpio(enable pin) high.
    req_length = modbus_send_raw_request(ctx, raw_req, 6 * sizeof(uint8_t)); //write
    usleep(9050); //waite until write is finished
    write(fd,"0",1);//After write(), make gpio low to receive messages from sensor.
    int response_length = modbus_receive_confirmation(ctx, rsp);`

this code is working sometimes..... it also not the best answer.
the result is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bqzu3hi9gV4
After 1'22, it's working.

enable Pin is connected to FPGA (ZYNQ)

It is difficult to add other circuit to control enable pin.
it is more convenience to make a design on the FPGA.
( i.stack.imgur.com/f7Ebg.png )
should I control this by software?(controlling gpio) 
or Hardware?

Let me know the best way, approach.. Thank you.

Comment: SP485 probably refers to the [RS-485 transceiver by Sipex - nowadays Exar](https://www.exar.com/product/interface/serial-transceivers/rs485-422/sp3485). It translates to/from UART/TTL levels to/from differential RS-422/RS-485 levels. No idea where you got RS-232 from.

Comment: Probably the enable pins are left floating. There's no pull resistors present on the schematic. How do you guarantee signal levels on the enable pins? Is it always driven by an output from the FPGA? This seems to be a hardware problem rather than a programming problem. Such questions are more suitable for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have known RS-232 and RS485 are kinds of UART. I am now confused. anyway. Yes. There is no any resistor in the schematic. Pull up or down resiter is meaningless As I will controll these pin using tri-state pin(FPGA) which act as pull up and down.